# how to hide navigation bar while scrolling up in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have implemented scrollview which is working fine but when i start scrolling it up i am getting navigation view and as soon as i stop scrolling it hides.

Is there any way that we can remove it or dont show it while scrolling. basically i dont want navigation view for that screen

I tried below things but did not worked.

```
NavigationView  {
    ScrollView(viewmodel: self.viewmodel)
        .onAppear{
            self.viewmodel.abc()
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
}
```

scrollview is kind of below

```
struct ScrollView :UIViewRepresentable{
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return ScrollView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var viewmodel : Viewmodel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let view  = UIScrollView()
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: PlayerView(viewmodel: self.viewmodel))
        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Screen.maxWidth, height: Screen.maxHeight*CGFloat(viewmodel.player.count))
        
        view.contentSize = CGSize(width: Screen.maxWidth, height: Screen.maxHeight*CGFloat(viewmodel.videoplayer.count))
        
        view.addSubview(childView.view)
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=false
        view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.isPagingEnabled=true
        view.delegate=context.coordinator
        return view
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine with standard ScrollView, is your ScrollView custom one? Needed demo code to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your makeUIView function:

```
childView.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```